# jQuery $.ajax call to Web Api with string arrays

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to call a .net Web Api method via jquery's $.ajax. When I pass in

var process = "first process",
var nameArray = ["first", "second"],
var valueArray = ["val1", "val2"]

and then:

```
 $.ajax({
url: jsonFeed,
data: {process: process, nameArray: nameArray, valueArray: valueArray},
    etc...
```

I have a ASP.NET Web Api method:

```
  public string GetResponseToken(string process, string[] nameArray, string[] valueArray)
```

When I run everything, I receive an error message:

"Can't bind multiple parameters ('nameArray' and 'valueArray') to the request's content."

Does anyone know why this is, or how I can fix it to accept my arrays?

Comment: What is type of your ajax call GET or POST?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The Web.API parameter/model binder work differently than the MVC one. You need to tell it that you wan't to bind all of your arguments from the query string with the `[FromUri]` attribute:

```
public string GetResponseToken(
      [FromUri]string process, 
      [FromUri]string[] nameArray, 
      [FromUri]string[] valueArray)
{
    //... 
}
```

In the long run (e.g the above mentioned approach won't work if you your request type is a POST) you should consider to use a parameter object instead of having multiple arguments.

```
public string GetResponseToken([FromUri]ResponseTokenRequest request)
{
    //...
}

public class ResponseTokenRequest
{
    public string Process { get; set; }
    public string[] NameArray { get; set; }
    public string[] ValueArray { get; set; }
}
```

You can learn about the Wep.API parameter binding in the following articles:

- [How WebAPI does Parameter Binding](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jmstall/archive/2012/04/16/how-webapi-does-parameter-binding.aspx)
- [Passing multiple POST parameters to Web API Controller Methods](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2012/May/08/Passing-multiple-POST-parameters-to-Web-API-Controller-Methods)